Date column with associated MAX count value
MySQL 8.0.40
Sakila database
The following two queries correctly return two columns: Rental date and the total count for each date.
SELECT
 DATE(rental_date) AS 'Rental date',
 COUNT(DATE(rental_date)) AS 'Count for each day'
FROM rental
GROUP BY
 DATE(rental_date);

SELECT
 DATE(rental_date) AS 'Rental date',
 COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM rental
GROUP BY
 DATE(rental_date);

This query correctly returns the MAX value (679).
SELECT
 MAX(Count)
FROM
 (SELECT
   COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
  FROM rental
  GROUP BY
   DATE(rental_date)) as DailyCount;

However, what I want is to return the date that has the max value along with the max value:
2005-07-31  679

This is my last attempt but it still generates errors:
SELECT
 DATE(rental_date) AS 'Rental date',
 COUNT(*)
FROM rental
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT
     MAX(Count)
    FROM (
          SELECT
           DATE(rental_date) AS 'Rental date',
           COUNT(*) AS Count
          FROM rental
           GROUP BY
            DATE(rental_date) AS X
    )
);

SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS X
    )
)' at line 14

Error position: line: 13


Why do you think you need AS X after GROUP BY? Just get rid of that.

Because it generates a specific error telling me I am required to assign an alias."Every derived table must have its own alias"

But you didn't give the alias to a table. Put it after the end of the subquery.

This might do the trick
SELECT
 DATE(rental_date) AS 'Rental date',
 COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM rental
GROUP BY
 DATE(rental_date)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1

For fetching all the rows having max count, below query can help.
SELECT
    DATE(rental_date) AS `Rental Date`,
    COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM rental
GROUP BY
    DATE(rental_date)
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT MAX(`Count`) 
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Count`
        FROM rental
        GROUP BY rental_date
    ) AS m
);



This won't work if there's more than one date with the maximum.

@Barmar thanks for pointing out. But then the question arises, what do you want me to output in such scenario?

Output all the dates with the maximum.

ok, let me update my answer then.

The alias should be on the subquery, not after GROUP BY.
SELECT
 DATE(rental_date) AS `Rental date`,
 COUNT(*)
FROM rental
GROUP BY `Rental date`
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT MAX(Count)
    FROM (
          SELECT
           DATE(rental_date) AS `Rental date`,
           COUNT(*) AS Count
          FROM rental
          GROUP BY `Rental date`
    ) AS X
);


This did solve the alias error, but still does not produce the desired outcome (SQL Error [1140] [42000]: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'sakila.rental.rental_date'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by)

You were missing the GROUP BY in the main query.

That was it.  Much appreciated.
